# PHP - PDO execute with a string variable

Tags: php, pdo

I just don't understand why this is working:

```
 $stmt->execute([':id' => '*',':email' => 'email@gmail.com',':password' => '123456789',]);
```

and this not (Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens):

```
$params = "':id' => '*',':email' => 'email@gmail.com',':password' => '123456789',"
$stmt->execute([$params]);
```

This got me crazy!

I've tried to look for other similar question but i can't find any.

**EDIT:**
I'm trying this way:

```
$params = array("qualsiasi"=>"*", "email"=>"email@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456789");
$q = "SELECT :qualsiasi FROM utenti WHERE email = :email AND password = :password";
$stmt = $db->prepare($q);
foreach ($params as $key => $param){
$token = ":" . $key;
$stmt->bindParam($token , $param);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

It works, PDO execute, but it doesn't match values in the db, but it should. I really don't know why...

Comment: An array of multiple items is not the same as an array with one string item.

Comment: The real question is why you tried that in the first place? → http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Amber should answer this with a little more detail.

Comment: Because i've an array like this: $results = array("token1"=>"*", "email"=>"email@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456789");

I try to use it as execute's argument because i need to run it in a function that has an array like that as its argument

Comment: If you already had an array, then why did it become a string all of a sudden?

Comment: I tried: $stmt->execute($params); but it doesn't work, so i tried to create a string

Answer (score 3):

`[$params]` with `$params` being a string does not create an array with multiple keys, no matter what the string is. It just creates an array with a single numerically-keyed item, where the value of that one item is the entire `$params` string.

As such, you wind up passing a single-item array to `->execute()`, which thus does not work for a query with multiple parameters.

**N.B.** that even if your query had a single parameter, you'd still wind up passing the wrong value, because instead of `[':foo' => 'bar']` (key `:foo`, value `:bar`) it'd be passing `["':foo' => ':bar'"]` (index `0`, value `':foo' => ':bar'`).

Comment: Thank you very much, i understood. I've tried to put inside an array but this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
$params = "':id' => '*',':email' => 'email@gmail.com',':password' => '123456789',"
$stmt->execute([$params]);
```

turns into

```
$stmt->execute(["':id' => '*',':email' => 'email@gmail.com',':password' => '123456789',"]);
```

It's not same as

```
$stmt->execute([
    ':id' => '*',
    ':email' => 'email@gmail.com',
    ':password' => '123456789',
]);
```

See the difference? A string put between the square brackets does not turn itself into a `key => value` array. It just becomes a one-value array with the string being your only value.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. it doesn't work using a well formatted array too: $results = array("token1"=>"*", "email"=>"email@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456789");